# Problem with tor and gpg key

Tags: tor-install

I'm trying to install tor on Debian but I have a problem.

When I put this command:

```
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

I have a

```
gpg: warning : nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
```

message

Thanks in advance

Yes I did this first

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv      A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
```

Comment: Did you run this first? `gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89`

Comment: Yes I did it first.

Comment: can you provide a verbose output?

Comment: @Alexey Vesnin.                                                                                   Sorry but I don't understand. What command should I run?

Comment: use `--verbose` command-line key when you're executing your GPG commands and post an output here.

Comment: I tried: gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add - --verbose and gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add --verbose. I always have the same message: gpg: warning : nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Comment: What is the output of the `--recv` command? That's where the problem is.

Comment: gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add - --recv                                                                      gpg: warning : nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Comment: nope, just run `gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89` and tell us the output

Comment: gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89     |    gpg: requesting key 886DDD89 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
gpg: key 886DDD89: « deb.torproject.org archive signing key » not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

Comment: and `gpg -a --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89`?

Comment: gpg -a --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1

mQENBEqg7GsBCACsef8koRT8UyZxiv1Irke5nVpte54TDtTl1za1tOKfthmHbs2I
4DHWG3qrwGayw+6yb5mMFe0h9Ap9IbilA5a1IdRsdDgViyQQ3kvdfoavFHRxvGON
tknIyk5Goa36GMBl84gQceRs/4Zx3kxqCV+JYXE9CmdkpkVrh2K3j5+ysDWfD/kO
dTzwu3WHaAwL8d5M…………….
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

But when I run su and I write down my root password, I have: gpg -a --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89   gpg:warning : nothing exported

Answer (score 1):

Try using: `gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89` instead.  The server at `keys.gnupg.net` no longer exists.

So the new command should be:

`gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -`